# How is the Github handling so many public keys

Tags: git, ssh, github, openssh

I'm wondering, how Github is able to handle so many public keys, which are used for authenticating over ssh.

One user owns aprox 3 certificates and how many users are on Github - millions? Easy multiplication gives us millions of certificates. It isn't in one `.ssh/authorized_keys` file for user git I guess, right?

They have own ssh server implemented, or exists any mod for OpenSSH solving this kind of problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Very interesting question. I look forward to the answers.

Comment: Consider that `git:` URLs have the username embedded, and it becomes far less of an issue. What is an issue (imo) is that they will tell you if you're using a duplicate key, and refuse to accept it (makes shared accounts harder).

Comment: @parsifal: github's ssh "urls" (we're not really taking about urls though) look like "git@github.com:sourcejedi/Bonfire.git".  (My github is "sourcejedi", not "git").  The other options (which are real urls) don't include a username part.

Comment: @sourcejedi - both `https://github.com/sourcejedi/Bonfire.git` and `git://github.com/sourcejedi/Bonfire.git` have your username in them. And unless your GH account is different from mine, you'll see the same thing in the read-write URLs.

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have mentioned https and git urls, as they don't use your ssh key.  If you read the question, you can see it refers to "user git".  An unmodified sshd would obviously use that user, and would not try to search for a username inside the command passed to ssh.  Hence the question about modifications to sshd.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They have patched sshd to lookup key in the MySQL database:

https://github.com/blog/530-how-we-made-github-fast

Comment: I read that article some time ago, but I completely overlooked this part. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Answer is, how mentions rkhayrov, that the Github uses patched OpenSSH daemon.

For those who are interested in this problem, I found the source code (guess where's the code hosted ;)) - http://github.com/norbauer/openssh-for-git